# Disable Crash Reporting in MixPanel

Tags: ios, mixpanel, crittercism

From MixPanel release 3.1.5 (iOS) there are few events which are automatically tracked, one of them are Crash Events. Is there any way to disable Crash reporting. It does conflict with Appteligent/Crittercism

*Release Notes*

https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/which-common-mobile-events-can-mixpanel-collect-on-my-behalf-automatically

https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone/releases/tag/v3.1.5

Answer (score 1):

Looks like disabling Crash Reporting in Mixpanel is not possible as of now. However If I switch the initialization of both then I am able to see crash reports on Apteligent. That means first Mixpanel and then initialize Crittercism

Answer (score 0):

Using another crash reporting tool along with Apteligent SDK is something which is not recommended. However, if you still wish to do so, you may check the following article in order to troubleshoot interference being created from other tools. Hope this helps :

https://support.apteligent.com/articles/knowledge_base/How-to-troubleshoot-interference-from-other-Error-Handlers

Comment: I did used the troubleshooting steps and figured out that there is an interference with Mixpanel so that's why wanted to know is there any way to disable Crash reporting in Mixpanel

Comment: In that case, I would suggest contacting Mixpanel support, they must have something to hep here.